# Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: indices[0,0] = 302224 is not in [0, 13579)

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm getting the following error when parsing a visitor x item matrix through a tensorflow NN

I think it has something to do with the input_dim size but I cant figure out how to fix it.

Maybe the matrix is too sparse.

```
dtf_users.shape = (23368, 13579)

train =

    visitorid   itemid  y
    0   110 224322  0.500
    1   147 426635  0.500
    2   211 373907  0.500
    3   277 254879  0.500
    4   379 320130  0.625
    ... ... ... ...
    28121   1407339 15948   0.500
    28122   1407345 401746  0.500
    28123   1407377 151406  0.500
    28124   1407408 365945  0.500
    28125   1407568 62799   0.500

Model

    embeddings_size = 50 #len(dtf_users) + 1
    usr, prd = dtf_users.shape[0], dtf_users.shape[1]
    
    # Users (,1,embedding_size) and Reshape (,embedding_size)
    xusers_in = layers.Input(name="xusers_in", shape=(1,))
    xusers_emb = layers.Embedding(name="xusers_emb", input_dim=usr, output_dim=embeddings_size)(xusers_in)
    xusers = layers.Reshape(name='xusers', target_shape=(embeddings_size,))(xusers_emb)
    
    # Products (,1,embedding_size) and Reshape (,embedding_size)
    xproducts_in = layers.Input(name="xproducts_in", shape=(1,))
    xproducts_emb = layers.Embedding(name="xproducts_emb", input_dim=prd, output_dim=embeddings_size)(xproducts_in)
    xproducts = layers.Reshape(name='xproducts', target_shape=(embeddings_size,))(xproducts_emb)
    
    # Product (,1) values[-1,1]
    xx = layers.Dot(name='xx', normalize=True, axes=1)([xusers, xproducts])
    
    # Predict ratings (,1)
    y_out = layers.Dense(name="y_out", units=1, activation='linear')(xx)
    
    # Compile
    model = models.Model(inputs=[xusers_in,xproducts_in], outputs=y_out, name="CollaborativeFiltering")
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
    model.summary()
    
    # train
    training = model.fit(x=[train["visitorid"], train["itemid"]], y=train["y"], 
                         epochs=100, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, verbose=0, validation_split=0.3)
    model = training.model
```

```
Traceback
    
    InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
    ...
        File "c:\Users\damia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\embedding.py", line 208, in call
          out = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, inputs)
    Node: 'CollaborativeFiltering/xproducts_emb/embedding_lookup'
    indices[0,0] = 302224 is not in [0, 13579)
         [[{{node CollaborativeFiltering/xproducts_emb/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6263]
```

Comment: Your embedding layer has just 13579 embeddings (defined here `input_dim=prd,`) while you try to access number 302224, so you get an error. The embeddings are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: I'm confused to why the model try's to access am embedding outside of the layers created. How do i stop this from occuring?

Comment: It's your data. You have an itemid 302224, which is out of range for your embedding layer, so the layer complains

Comment: So my embeddings must contain all item id's to be able to fit the model?